# My old banner is not showing after update

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a very simple application for 1 year in Play Store, this application has a banner (banner1) on the main screen (MainActivity). It was the only ad for my application so yesterday I decided to add a new banner (banner2) on another screen (ListActivity).

I uploaded my update and it is already available in the Play Store, But I noticed in AdMob that the banner1 only has 137 impressions, the strange thing is that at this time (11:00) it always has more than 1200 impressions so I installed my application on 2 different devices (from Play Store ) and I noticed that in both the banner 1 never loads and the banner 2 is displayed without problem.

I did not make any changes in MainActivity, in AdMob the banner is enabled so I do not understand what may be happening.

Yesterday I also updated this data in my gradle:

Before:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Now:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
targetSdkVersion 31
```

After making that change I noticed that Android Studio was showing me a problem on the line

```
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This is the error displayed by Android Studio:

> Missing permissions required by BaseAdView.loadAd
> android.permission.INTERNET

- This error appears when displaying banner1 and banner2

I do not understand, supposedly that permission is no longer necessary, but I also have it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My low ad impressions issue is related to android studio error? How do I fix the error?

This is my code to display the ad:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadingAdAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
            loadingAdAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```